# Simulating exception-like bevaviour in bash

Tags: bash

In Bash, is there some way to simulate exceptions?

E.g. in a test function, i have several test statements

```
test_foo_and_bar() {
    expect_foo $1
    expect_bar $2
}

expect_foo() {
    [[ $1 != "foo" ]] && return 1
}

expect_bar() {
    [[ $1 != "bar" ]] && return 1
}
```

Now, what I would want is that if `expect_foo` fails, execution stops and returns to the caller of function `test_foo_and_bar`.

Is something like that possible? I know you could do something like this:

```
test_foo_and_bar() {
    expect_foo $1 || return 2
    expect_bar $2 || return 2
}
```

But I am interested in alternative solutions (if there are any).

**EDIT**

While the proposed solutions are pretty good, I have one further requirement. After an *exception* has occured, I still need to perform cleanup. So just exiting is not an option.

What I effectivly need, in Java-speak, is some sort of `finally` clause.

Comment: The standard way to get exception-like behavior in sh is using `set -e`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12337030/1600898 for details.

Answer (score 1):

A quick hack that comes to my mind is to use subshelling and `exit`:

```
test_foo_and_bar() {
    (
        expect_foo $1
        expect_bar $2
    )
}

expect_foo() {
    [[ $1 != "foo" ]] && exit 1
}   

expect_bar() {
    [[ $1 != "bar" ]] && exit 1
}
```

This way, any failure will cause the whole `test_foo_and_bar` block to terminate. However, you will always have to remember to call `expect_foo` and `_bar` in a subshell to avoid terminating the main program.

Additionally, you'll likely want to replace the `exit` with a custom `die` function which will output some verbose error as well.

Comment: Could some of the `&& exit 1` be avoided when `set -e / +e` is set in appropriate places?

Comment: Yes, of course — well, as long as you don't want specific failure messages. However, you should be aware of the exact `set -e` semantics (i.e. which things actually exit and which don't). It's a bit scary and sometimes far from being obvious (esp. with `&&` and `||`), so I'd personally avoid that.

Comment: Also, functions called in a subshell can no longer affect the current shell, so there are limitations to which functions can be used with this scheme.